# Is there any way to make an iterative plot that rotates the axes at every iteration

Tags: matlab, for-loop, rotation, plot, axes

I would like to make a plot then rotate the x-y axes by an angle;
then make the same plot again on the rotated axes, then rotate axes again for the next similar plot

Something like this:

```
hold all;

for k= 0:1:10
    % rotate-axis-about-origin(angle * k)
    plot(XY(:,1),XY(:,2));
end
```

Is there any way to achieve what I am proposing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a rotation matrix inside the loop:

```
hold all;

% test vector and matrix
x = (1:10)';
y = x.^2;    
XY0 = [x y];

angle = 1/180*pi;   % 1 degree

for k= 0:1:10
    % rotate-axis-about-origin(angle * k)
    rot = [cos(angle*k) sin(angle*k);-sin(angle*k) cos(angle*k)];
    XY = XY0*rot;
    plot(XY(:,1),XY(:,2));
end
```

XY0 is the original matrix and XY varies each step.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by rolling the camera at each step via [`camroll`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/camroll.html). Here's a toy working example for plotting sine:

```
hold all

x = -3:0.01:3;
y = sin(x);
angle = 1; % in degrees
for k = 1:90 % 90 steps
    plot(x,y, 'k');
    camroll(angle); % roll 'angle' degrees at each step
    drawnow
    pause(0.05)
end
```

Comment: change camroll(angle) to camroll(angle*k) or you will have the axes fixed on the same angle at each loop pass.

Comment: No. I'm using R2011b and it rotates incrementally at each step.

Comment: This works as petrichor says when using R2012a (even though to me angle*k makes more sense).

It however overwrites the plots before it. If it left them, this solution would have suited my needs.

Comment: Ok, I use R2009a, so that explains why it didn't work for me.

Comment: @DeanKayton I'm happy that it helped. If this answer is what you need, please accept it as the answer to your problem.

Comment: It almost helps, except in this case R. Schifini's answer works the way I had in mind, by future plots not overwriting past ones.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Then, a bit clarification would be better in your question. You ask how to rotate the axes. But you actually wanted to ask how to rotate the data then. Anyway, happy to see your poblem is solved.

Comment: I'm so sorry petrichor, I just looked at my question and realised I ommitted the part where I wanted the previous plots to stay. I clearly wasn't thinking along the correct lines when writing the question. To everyone who might stumble upon this page, this answer provides a neat solution to incrementally rotating your plot. It is a very useful answer :)

Comment: No problem :) I just wanted to clarify for the people seeking for a similar question. Best.